# JPA unable to retrieve child entries for parent-child mapping

Tags: jpa, orm, mapping, parent-child

I am trying to map a parent and child relationship with-in the same class:

```
public class Category {        

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "categorySeq", sequenceName = "category_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "categorySeq")

    @Column(name = "category_id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "code", nullable = true)
    private String code;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "parent_id", nullable = true)
    private Long parentId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public Category parentCategory;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentCategory", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<Category> subCategories = new ArrayList<Category>();

}
```

When I do a GET on category i only get the parentCategory and the subCategories comes-out as null. I want both the parent and child entries to be returned on a GET. Any ideas what's wrong here?

Comment: Huh? You define a sequence generator yet then define to use IDENTITY strategy (instead of SEQUENCE). Makes no sense. At all. IDENTITY is to use "AUTOINCREMENT" not a sequence

Comment: Oh yeah it should be SEQUENCE. thanks.

Comment: Why are you mapping parent_id as both a basic mapping and as a relationship?  Since you've marked the relationship as effectively read-only, when you add in a parent, are you also adding in the child to the parent's list of subCategories?  I'd recommend you switch it so that parentId is read-only and parent_id is set from the relationship so that JPA can set the field for you when it retrieves a parent's sequence value, and verify that you are setting both sides of this bidirectional relationship.

Comment: Thanks for point it out Chris.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so on the reverse side of the relationship i had to fetch it eagerly by setting FetchType.EAGER, it retrieves the child entries but now Jackson complains about infinite looping for which i had to use @JsonIgnore. But if i use @JsonIgore it defeats the purpose of this question since i needed to see the child entries.

But i guess i realized that to parse the whole hierarchy tree i can do that by recursively traversing the parent of each child.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentCategory", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
public List<Category> subCategories = new ArrayList<Category>();
```